# Akka Java API - How to extend AbstractActor and use both Timers and Stash functions

Tags: java, akka, actor

Basically I want an Actor that makes use of both **Timers** and **Stash** functionality.

In Scala we can do following - `extends AbstractActor with Timer with Stash`

In Java I found two classes - `AbstractActorWithTimers` and `AbstractActorWithStash`.

Unfortunately I cannot extend both the classes in Java.

Any recommended way to do so in Java??

Comment: May I ask what are you trying to accomplish? Are you implementing a StateMachine?

Answer (score 0):

Even I was stuck in the same problem. 
I wanted to create a state machine and I required both stash and timer for same.

So in this case I was left with two options:-

- Use AbstractFSMWithStash:- This I did-not prefer as I was not sure if
  it was scalabel in my solution
- Use Typed Actors where you can actually compose the timer and stash, please refer to code below with test case:-

  ```
  import akka.actor.testkit.typed.javadsl.TestKitJunitResource;
  import akka.actor.typed.ActorRef;
  import akka.actor.typed.Behavior;
  import akka.actor.typed.javadsl.Behaviors;
  import akka.actor.typed.javadsl.StashBuffer;
  import akka.actor.typed.javadsl.TimerScheduler;
  import org.junit.ClassRule;
  import org.junit.Test;
  import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitSuite;

  import java.time.Duration;

  public class CountingActor extends JUnitSuite {

    public static final class DeviceMessage implements Msg{
      private int id;

      public DeviceMessage(int id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      public int getId() {
        return id;
      }
    }

    interface Msg{}
    private static final class TimeOut implements Msg{}


    private static final Object TIMER_KEY = new Object();

    private static final StashBuffer<Msg> buffer = StashBuffer.create(10000);

    public static Behavior<Msg> behavior(Duration after) {
      return Behaviors.withTimers(timers -> active(timers, after));
    }


    private static Behavior<Msg> idle(TimerScheduler<Msg> timers,
        Duration after) {
      return Behaviors.receive(Msg.class)
        .onMessage(DeviceMessage.class, (ctx, msg) -> {
            System.out.println("in idle state got message:"+msg.getId());
            buffer.stash(msg);
          return Behaviors.same();
        })
        .onMessage(TimeOut.class,(ctx,msg)->{
            System.out.println("in idle state got TimeOut");
            timers.cancel(TIMER_KEY);
            return buffer.unstashAll(ctx,active(timers,after));
        })
        .build();
    }

    private static Behavior<Msg> active(TimerScheduler<Msg> timers,
       Duration after) {
      return Behaviors.receive(Msg.class)
        .onMessage(DeviceMessage.class, (ctx, msg) -> {
            System.out.println("got message:"+msg.getId());
            timers.startSingleTimer(TIMER_KEY, new TimeOut(), after);
            System.out.println(" going to idle state " );
            return idle(timers,after);
        })

        .build();
      }

      @ClassRule
      public static final TestKitJunitResource testKit = new TestKitJunitResource();

      @Test
      public void stashingExample() throws Exception {
          ActorRef<Msg> ref= testKit.spawn(CountingActor.behavior(Duration.ofSeconds(2)));

          for(int i=0;;i++){
              ref.tell(new DeviceMessage(i));
          }


     }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I stumbled upon this problem and we circumvented it by creating an abstract class in a scala project and later on extending it in Java.

This scala project is actually a module in our maven-multi-module project that uses akka (classic). The project contains this single abstract class with no body:

```
import akka.actor.{AbstractActor, Stash, Timers}

/**
  * An abstract actor that has both stash and timers.
  */
abstract class AbstractActorWithStashAndTimers extends AbstractActor with Stash with Timers {
}
```

Once you have compiled your scala project into a jar, and have that jar on your Java project classpath, you use it in Java like any other abstract actor class from akka:

```
public class MyConcreteActor extends AbstractActorWithStashAndTimers {
    @Override
    public final Receive createReceive() {
         // you can use stash() and timers() here.
    }
}
```